# What is a reasonable file size for a 4 minute video on the web?

Tags: html, video, compression

I am working on a site that will have a video on it. I am using HTML5 with a flash fallback and am hosting the video on the site (the client does not want to use Vimeo, YouTube, etc.). The video is a little over 4 minutes long and I have compressed the video down to 12.7MB for the mp4 format and around 23MB for webm and ogv. Are these file sizes too large? I can maybe get them smaller, but the quality really suffers. I also have the entire Adobe Creative Suite, so if someone has a good way to compress a video really well, while maintaing quality and a high resolution, I'm all ears!

Thanks!

Comment: Totally depends on your target demographic, if you are targeting mobile phone users or it is probably too much. If your target is 20/30 year olds on their pc this is perfectly acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty acceptable.  Keep in mind that this four minute video will load fully in a little over 10 *seconds* on most consumer-level broadband connections.

Comment: In the United States or other countries with developed infrastructure that is.  If some of the audience happens to be in less developed countries load times may still be significant.

Comment: thanks! The audience will be all from the US (though some of them will probably be on older systems, etc.). I just wanted to make sure I was in the ballpark and wasn't way too big. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Eric: Pretty sure that's implied, but as Andrew asked a generalized question without specifying where his customers are I felt comfortable offering an answer with a similar level of detail.  That being said, the MP4 file will be streamable without buffering at 54KB/sec and will be streamable with a one-minute buffer at 38KB/sec.  Anyone with less bandwidth than that would probably be better served by a textual or slideshow presentation of the information anyway.

Comment: @Andrew, no problem.  I'd actually probably go for higher quality except for targeting mobile phone viewers.

Comment: I actually just did the math on this yesterday. At today's (2014) internet speed (mine averages out around 48Mbps), a 70MB mp4 video should download in exactly 11.6 seconds... theoretically.

Comment: But I just checked my _actual_ speed at [Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net/) and got 7.70Mbps... which is sad.

Comment: Unfortunately, while we have some areas with faster broadband and some areas new to broadband since 2011, overall speeds just aren't that different. The big, big change has been mobile broadband speed, which is now the same kind of crapshoot cable internet was in the early 2000s.